# PHPdoc Регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня проблема с захватом в регулярных выражениях:

Есть функция:

```
$f = function($doc)
{

 $data = [];

 preg_match_all("/[\s]*[\/\*\s]*(.+)[\/\*\s]*/i", $doc, $matches);

 var_dump($matches);

};
```

Парсим php doc блок такого вида:

```
$f("
    /**
     * test
     *
     * @param string \$comment
     *
     * @return array
     */

     ");
```

Дамп (тут все как и должно быть).

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "test"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "@param string $comment"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "@return array"
  }
```

Если распарсить блок такого вида:

```
$f("/** @var array ___TEST___ */");
```

То в конце захватываются ненужные символы: пробел и */ ( */), хотя в правиле регулярного выражения это прописано `[\/\*\s]*/i`

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "@var array ___TEST___ */"
  }
```

Как исправить данное выражение, чтобы оно не захватывало эти последние 3 символа?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве альтернативного решения посмотрите в сторону использования штатного средства [разбивки на лексемы](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.token-get-all.php).

[Пример вытаскивания конкретного поля из PHPDoc](https://github.com/rjhdby/php-api-skeleton/blob/master/src/class/core/Controller.php) в списке файлов `.php`

```
if ($token[0] === T_DOC_COMMENT && preg_match('/@api-call/m', $token[1]) !== 0) {
    $method = preg_replace("/.*@api-call\s+(\w+).*/s", "$1", $token[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Постройте шаблон таким образом: `'~(?<=\s)[^*/]+(?=\b)~i'` И тогда будут найдены все необходимые вхождения, без использования подмасок.