# Регулярное выражение php захватывает не по правилу

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как исправить данное регулярное выражение, чтобы оно не возвращало те символы, которые указаны в конце (символы `/`, `*` и `пробел`)

Вот код:

```
preg_match_all("/[\/\*\s]*(.+)[\/\*\s]*/i", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Если передать этому регулярному выражению строку `*/* str __#@33$*/%^& //*`, то должно вернуть `str __#@33$*/%^&`, но возвращает `str __#@33$*/%^& //*`.

Вот эти 4 символа `//*` на конце должны были отпасть, т.к. в правиле указано:

/[/\*\s]*(.+)**[/\*\s]***/i

Я так понял, что `.+` захватывает все, не проверяя, что на конце не должно быть `//*`

Как исправить это выражение? Так же этих символов `//*` не должно быть ТОЛЬКО на конце, в `.+` они присутствовать могут, поэтому варианты типа `[^\/\*\s]+` сразу отпадают.

Также, если составить выражение вида `/[\/\*\s]*(.+)[\/\*\s]+/i`, то результат уже будет без звездочки на конце: `str __#@33$*/%^& //`.

Получается можно сделать так: `/[\/\*\s]*(.+)[\/\*\s]{4}/i` и результат будет как и нужен: `str __#@33$*/%^&`, но символов на конце может быть и не 4, а больше или меньше, или же может вообще не быть.

Может быть что-то связано с ленивыми и жадными проверками? Я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: `.+` захватывает все, что может захватить. Это называется жадный захват. Что бы снизить жадность надо использовать знак вопроса. `.+?` тогда он будет захватывать только до первого символа подпадающего под следующее выражение

Comment: @user269067 я вам вчера ответил в этой теме:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724877/phpdoc-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @Эдуард он не работает

Comment: И плюс он не захватывает символы `/*` в `.+`

Comment: @Mike тогда результат будет таким: https://goo.gl/pQbnQu (даже если и потом все это соединить в одну строку, то все равно там не захватываются пробелы, если будет строка, типа `*// str1 str 2/**`)

Comment: @user269067 Вам * в конце мешает, она говорит что те символы в скобках не обязательны. и тогда `.+?` захватывает по одному символу, потому что выражение уже не интересует то что после. https://regex101.com/r/syQRTQ/1

Comment: правда все равно не так как вы ожидаете, потому что у вас в строке есть косая черта и с этим надо что то делать. видимо как то совершенно по иному определять, что вам нужно, а что нет

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы то, что вам нужно:

```
<?php

$str = '*/* str__#@33$*/%^&* //*';

$patt = '~(?<=\s)[\S\s]+(?=\s)~i';
preg_match_all($patt, $str , $a);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($a); echo '</pre>'; //str__#@33$*/%^&*
```

Comment: @user269067 чтоб хорошо разбираться в регулярках, читайте "Регулярные выражения" Джеффри Фридла.

Comment: @user269067 вы изменили ваш пп, поэтому я подправил шаблон с учётом изменений.